# Apertium Language Pair Installation

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I stuck in installing a language pair for Apertium in Ubuntu. I followed the installation instruction in this [Wiki page](http://wiki.apertium.org/wiki/Minimal_installation_from_SVN) but it's not worked. The error is showed below:

```
lrx-comp apertium-fr-es.fr-es.eco.lrx fr-es.eco.autolex.bin
lrx-comp: error while loading shared libraries: liblttoolbox3-3.3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
make: *** [fr-es.eco.autolex.bin] Error 127
```

I tried to do follow the troubleshooting page:
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$prefix/lib`
But it's not worked too
My directory structure can display like this:
`home/local` and `home/source` that contains all the tools and Apertium. What should I do, please advise?

Comment: Could you check if liblttoolbox3-3.3.so.0 exists in $HOME/local/lib? If yes, try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/local/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}`

Comment: I saw it existed in `$HOME/local/lib` in the properties it showed like this `/home/thovo/local/lib`, was it correct? I tried `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/local/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}` but nothing happen

Comment: `$HOME` is a variable that point to `/home/user`, so if `thovo` is your current user, `$HOME`'s value is `/home/thovo`. Did you follow `Set up environment` section in [Wiki page](http://wiki.apertium.org/wiki/Minimal_installation_from_SVN) and set PREFIX, LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH in your $HOME/.bashrc? If yes, could you post exactly lines you added?

Comment: When I followed the intrusction to set up environment, whenever I typed , the terminal show nothing, was it correct?

Comment: Yes, if you type (for example): `PREFIX=$HOME/local` terminal shows nothing, you simple define PREFIX variable in the environment and you can see this variable value by typing `echo $PREFIX` that will show `/home/thovo/local`. These command are not permanent and if you logout you lose this value. You should add those lines in $HOME/.bashrc file. Open this file with `gedit $HOME/.bashrc` and add variable definition as mentioned in Wiki page. Save it and type `source $HOME/.bashrc`

Comment: I will try and let you know later. Thank a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some helps from my professor, I think it worked now:

When I checked the `usr/local/lib` it didn't show `ldtoolbox` or other library so I decided to check out all the repository and started to install from this directory.

`$ cd /usr/local/lib`

Follow the same step on this [guide](http://wiki.apertium.org/wiki/Minimal_installation_from_SVN) but when install from this directory, everything must begin with `sudo`

After finished all of this process, I used the fr-es language pair:

Move to the directory has the language pair:
`cd apertium-fr-es/`

Write some test
`echo 'Mon ami' | apertium -d . fr-es-tagger`
It would show: `^Mon<det><pos><m><sg>$ ^ami<n><m><sg>$^.<sent>$`
Or `echo 'Je vais allez chez toi' | apertium -d . fr-es`
It would show : `Voy vais en tú`

Answer (score 1):

Apertium now has a nightly package repo, so installation of development pairs is a lot simpler than it used to be. You can either install language pairs just as a "user" with apt-get, or, if you want to develop or learn from it, you can check out the source data for the language pair and compile that.

### Add the repo

Whatever you want to do, first you have to add the apt repo, since none of the recent Apertium packages are in the regular Ubuntu repos yet:

```
wget http://apertium.projectjj.com/apt/install-nightly.sh
sudo bash install-nightly.sh
```

### Installing a pair just for translating

Then, if your goal is just to translate text (not doing any development on it), do:

```
sudo apt-get -f install apertium-fr-es
```

Now you can try

```
$ echo 'Mon ami' | apertium fr-es
Mi amigo
# or document translation:
$ apertium fr-es fr.odt es.odt
```

You can do `apt-cache show apertium-all-pairs` to show all available language pairs installable with apt-get.

### Compiling language data yourself for development / learning

If you want to compile some language data from SVN (e.g. to work on pairs-in-progress or look at the tagger output etc.), you instead install this:

```
sudo apt-get -f install locales build-essential automake subversion pkg-config gawk libtool apertium-all-dev
```

Then, assuming you want your apertium development stuff to be in ~/apertium:

```
mkdir -p ~/apertium
cd ~/apertium
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/unhammer/apertium-get/master/apertium-get
chmod +x apertium-get
./apertium-get fr-es
```

You should now be able to test it:

```
$ cd apertium-fr-es
$ echo 'Mon ami' | apertium -d . fr-es-tagger
^Mon<det><pos><m><sg>$ ^ami<n><m><sg>$^.<sent>$
```

The list of development pairs available this way is much longer, use `~/apertium/apertium-get -l` to see all the pairs sorted by their [development status](http://wiki.apertium.org/wiki/Category:Repository).

### More info

See: http://wiki.apertium.org/wiki/Prerequisites_for_Debian